# CakePHP crontab intl

Tags: cakephp, cron

I create a crontab for execute de cakephp-queue but it returns!
You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP

Not working: `*/1  *  *  *  *  MY_FULL_PATH_TO_APP && bin/cake queue runworker`

I run `php -m | grep intl` it returns **intl**!

When I execute cake and make a request, it works well, but with crontab, it not works!

From crontab http request, it works well too!

Working: `*/1 * * * * wget http://af99d912.ngrok.io/api/v4/usuarios/checar.json`

SO macOS!

Comment: try from crontab php -m  >> text.txt

Comment: @Salines I did and there is no intl inside text.txt! When I run in the console php -m, it's there!

Comment: In same way check php -v or php -i. Your cron use different php config.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your configuration, CLI and webserwer can use different `php.ini` files. And thats probably your case. First run: `php -i | grep "Configuration File"` from CLI, it should output your `php.ini` file location. Open it with your favourite text editor and enable intl there.